# reading excel file in jave and produce xml as output

Tags: java

I have developed the runnable jar which will convert the sample excel file to xml file. it is working fine but i have problem where i need to loop based on particular column i.e see my excel for information

```
col  1     2               3              4 5           6             7
     10001 LD31PC15R013WD  DHULE_DEALER_2 1 C1C2003209  CHAKAN_PLANT  13-Apr-12
     10001 LD31PB15R0761WD DHULE_DEALER_2 1 C1C2003209  CHAKAN_PLANT  13-Apr-12
```

here every row converts to xml file but now if the column 5 has repetative data then it should go in one xml element by looping through it itself rather than creating new xml.

I have used apache poi for this utility.. Please help me if u need i will paste the code.

Comment: It would be good if you post the generated XML for this case.

Comment: I suggest to better define the problem you show, using your example, both your current xml file and what you would like the xml to look like. Also a code snippet of how you produce the file would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first create java beans for all your columns, once you parse excel you will need to populate javaBeans out of it. And from javaBeans you can create XML, it will have repeating elements.

You can have list(arrayList, linkedList) element for column5 in your JavaBean model.

Comment: OP's problem is not well defined: If the column 5 has repetitive data (compared to the last one, to the whole list?) it should go just one XML element (how to know **which one** to choose for XML?). Also, OP states that he/she can transform the Excel data into XML (not showing how, maybe using DTOs or VOs).